# Extra verbose ninja debug output

Tags: ninja

I have a `ninja` build that seems to get stuck at a particular command, however if I run the command manually it completes quickly with no problems.

Is there a way to get `ninja` to output more debugging information than `ninja -v` so I can work out why it is hanging?

Answer (score 5):

```
prebuilts/build-tools/linux-x86/bin/ninja -d list

debugging modes:
  stats        print operation counts/timing info
  explain      explain what caused a command to execute
  keepdepfile  don't delete depfiles after they're read by ninja
  keeprsp      don't delete @response files on success
multiple modes can be enabled via -d FOO -d BAR
```

Answer (score -2):

On cmakelists.txt

set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON CACHE BOOL "ON" FORCE)

Comment: why... would you **force** set it as a cache variable _inside_ a CMakeLists.txt? I mean, <expletive> your build users, am I right?

Comment: This applies to CMake and Make, not Ninja.

Comment: @starball It works on my machine, only with the `force`.